# Can't use foreach on a anonymous type

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the code below where I am trying to go through the child questions of my `qestAires` anonymous type.  When I get to the foreach loop i get the error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on
>   variables of type 'Question' because
>   'Question' does not contain a public
>   definition for 'GetEnumerator'

What do I need to do differently to get around this?

```
        var questAires = (from qs in dc.Questionnaires
                        from q in dc.Questions.Where(t => t.QuestionnaireId == qs.QuestionnaireID)
                        from r in dc.Responses.Where(qr => qr.QuestionID == q.QuestionId).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where qs.QuestionnaireID == QuestionnaireId
                        select new
                        {
                            qs.Description,
                            Questions = q,
                            Responses = r
                        }).Single();

        foreach(var question in questAires.Questions)
        {

        }
```

Comment: What type does `questAires` resolve to? You can check using Intellisense/tooltip in the debugger, just break on the line following the LINQ statement.

Comment: It sounds like questAires.Questions does not implement IEnumerable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`questAires.Questions` will only resolve to a single question, and you will get one `questAires` object for each question (which will cause `.Single()` to throw).

I guess you want something like this:

```
var questAires = (from qs in dc.Questionnaires
                  select new {
                      qs.Description,
                      Questions = from q in dc.Questions where q.QuestionnaireId == qs.QuestionnaireID
                                  select new {
                                      Question = q,
                                      Response = (from r in dc.Responses where r.QuestionID == q.QuestionId select r).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                  }
                 }).Single()
```

Answer (score 0):

q actually resolves to a single item from the enumerable `dc.Questions.Where(...)`, so yeah, you're only going to get a single item - not an enumerable - for Questions.